# Can Worldhoppers travel to the Spiritual Realm?

Tags: cosmere

There are really three parts to this question. One, can Worldhoppers use Perpendicularities to travel to the Spiritual Realm. Two, if so, has this been done. And three, is it possible to leave the Spiritual Realm once entered?

Comment: It is possible that Shards can manifest themselves wherever they wish (as in to visit other worlds) because of their 'residence' in the Spiritual Realm, and it may be that others could do the similar but it may be an 'energy limit' to the move, possibly a gravity well which (for example) the 'dead' cannot escape the realm without the backing of a Shard.

Comment: wait, Beyond [might not be](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/31/#e1729) the Spiritual Realm so

Comment: this is possibly going to be answered in one of the many future books

Answer (score 2):

[Elend](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/80/#e5335) (for example) has visited the Spiritual Realm, as have others who have 'ascended' by touching Shards though they did not fully commit themselves to being in the Realm.

The Spiritual Realm [isn't a place](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/369/#e11708) as it has [no spatial dimensions](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/69/#e6129) though Shards are [mostly located there](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/76/#e6304) and can [see other worlds](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/58/#e730) through the Spiritual Realm.

Comment: You should include the relevant quotes in your answer rather than just linking to them, links can break and it’s easier on the reader.